# Django admin template css is not loaded when deploy it in Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

this is the admin page deployed in heroku,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAQcJ.png)
here is my settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

deploy_settings.**init**.py

```
DEBUG = False
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

I tried to run python manage.py collectstatic locally, and run it in heroku bash also, but it didn't work. Do we actually need to run this command? or staticfiles are collected when pushing to heroku master?
I tried to add DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1 in heroku config variables, but it doesn't work.
one last note, I tried to install whitenoise and add it to the settings.py middlewars, and add
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage' in deply_settings.**init**.py but I recieved this error,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oMrd.png)
when

Comment: A simple google search turned up this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets - did you try this already?

Answer (score 0):

It is been fixed by removing this line in deploy_settings.init.py

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```